# Admob ads are showing only in unity editor

Tags: unity-game-engine, admob, ads

```
using UnityEngine;
```

using GoogleMobileAds.Api;
using System;

//Banner ad
public class Admob : MonoBehaviour
{
private BannerView adBanner;

```
private string idApp, idBanner;


void Start()
{
    idApp = "ca-app-pub-2932057985212846~3064197403";
    idBanner = "ca-app-pub-2932057985212846/7995098064";

    //MobileAds.Initialize(idApp);
    MobileAds.Initialize(initStatus => { });
    RequestBannerAd();
}



#region Banner Methods --------------------------------------------------

public void RequestBannerAd()
{
    adBanner = new BannerView(idBanner, AdSize.Banner, AdPosition.Bottom);
    AdRequest request = AdRequestBuild();
    adBanner.LoadAd(request);
}

public void DestroyBannerAd()
{
    if (adBanner != null)
        adBanner.Destroy();
}

#endregion


//------------------------------------------------------------------------
AdRequest AdRequestBuild()
{
    return new AdRequest.Builder().Build();
}

void OnDestroy()
{
    DestroyBannerAd();
}
```

}
I have a problem. My admob ads shows only when I am using the unity editor(in android). But when I build the app and then publish it to google play store I can't see any ads. And when I tried to use test ads by adding a test device it doesn't show ads.
But I only add test device by:

1. adding device.
2. give it a name.
3. write the mobile.
4. choose non in gestures.
   So please help me and tell me if I add test devices wrongly

Comment: Sorry But I don't know how to write all code in Stack overflow.